# Limit port 8080 access to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns

I am using SNS to connect to a Tomcat server on port 8080. The server runs on AWS/EC2. It is not a public server, I use it only to execute my code (triggered by the Notification delivered to it.)

How can I set up the "inbound rules" on my EC2 box so that only SNS can reach it? When I block the port, messages are not delivered. If I restrict it to the EC2 internal or external IP, the same. Apparently Notifications are delivered from "somewhere" that is not documented. And/or it is not a fixed IP [range]?

[I know how to secure the Tomcat server itself, but it would be nice if random port-scans can't even get to the server. I do see a number of (so far unsuccessful) access attempts in the Tomcat log.]

Comment: As far as I know sns notifications comes from the public network so you can only restrict the access from all the ips of the region but it's almost infeasible as they are hundreds of diffent cidr ipv4 and ipv6

Comment: my knowledge is confirmed here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=100662